# PFFile to PFImageView

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pffile

I'm having troubles displaying an image I'm taking from Parse in my iOS App. I decided to use the PFImageView. This is what I have so far:

I declared the PFImageView pic:

```
@IBOutlet var pic: PFImageView!
```

inside the query:

```
self.name.text = object["Name"] as String

var imagefile = object["image"] as PFFile
self.pic.file = imagefile
self.pic.loadInBackground()

self.desc.text = object["Description"] as String
```

It's really odd, because the others are working (name and description) and I am sure that I have a field named "image" in my database (yes small i). I always get this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Any insights into this?

Comment: check if your imageFile is nil or not?

Comment: this is exactly my problem @Joshua did you get a working solution?

Comment: what does your query look like @Joshua thanks

Answer (score -2):

Check if the file is nil

```
if object.objectForKey("image") != nil
{
var imagefile = object["image"] as PFFile
self.pic.file = imagefile
self.pic.loadInBackground()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
if let imagefile = object["image"] as PFFile {

    self.pic.file = imagefile
    self.pic.loadInBackground()
    }
```